# Assign value (stemming from configuration table) to group based on condition in column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `DT1`, containing a value per region. In a configuration table `DT2`, I have a mapping of each value per region to a variable `number_carrots`.

Is there an elegant data.table way of adding a column (`number_carrots`) to `DT1` stemming from the mapping in `DT2` ? I only managed to do this with a loop ...

To give an example. `DT1`is:

```
library(data.table)
region1 = c('Europe', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Africa')
value1  = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1)
DT1     = data.table(region1, value1)

> DT1
    region1 value1
1:  Europe      1
2:  Europe      2
3:  Africa      1
4:  Africa      2
5:  Europe      3
6:  Africa      1
```

And `DT2` is:

```
region2         = rep(c('Europe', 'Africa'), each = 3)
value2          = c(1:3, 1:3)
number_carrots  = c(10, 20, 30, 5, 15, 30)

DT2             = data.table(region2, value2, number_carrots)

> DT2
   region2 value2 number_carrots
1:  Europe      1             10
2:  Europe      2             20
3:  Europe      3             30
4:  Africa      1              5
5:  Africa      2             15
6:  Africa      3             30
```

Using, the mapping from `DT2`, I would like to add a column `number_carrots` to `DT1`:

```
> DT1
   region1 value1 number_carrots
1:  Europe      1             10
2:  Europe      2             20
3:  Africa      1              5
4:  Africa      2             15
5:  Europe      3             30
6:  Africa      1              5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested *to add a column `number_carrots` to `DT1`*.

This can be solved with an *update join* which modifies `DT1` by reference

```
DT1[DT2, on = .(region1 = region2, value1 = value2), number_carrots := i.number_carrots]
DT1
```

> ```
>    region1 value1 number_carrots
> 1:  Europe      1             10
> 2:  Europe      2             20
> 3:  Africa      1              5
> 4:  Africa      2             15
> 5:  Europe      3             30
> 6:  Africa      1              5
> ```